# Replicate a decompiled C code with Z3 library

Tags: z3

I'm learning Z3 and trying to reverse engineer an encryption algorithm with Z3 instead of writing it in C. I have the following psuedo-code decompiled by IDA:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  char *v3; // rsi
  unsigned int v4; // eax
  int v5; // eax
  __m128i *v6; // rbx
  __int64 v7; // rdx
  char v9; // [rsp+0h] [rbp-80h]
  __int64 v10; // [rsp+10h] [rbp-70h]
  int v11; // [rsp+18h] [rbp-68h]
  __int16 v12; // [rsp+1Ch] [rbp-64h]
  char v13; // [rsp+1Eh] [rbp-62h]
  char v14; // [rsp+1Fh] [rbp-61h]
  __m128i v15; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-60h]
  __int64 v16; // [rsp+30h] [rbp-50h]
  __int64 v17; // [rsp+38h] [rbp-48h]

  _main(argc, argv, envp);
  strcpy(v15.m128i_i8, "THE SECRET HAS BEEN REMOVED LOL");
  v3 = &v9;
  v4 = _time64(0i64);
  srand(v4);
  do
  {
    v5 = rand();
    *(++v3 - 1) = v5 - ((unsigned __int64)((0x7F807F81i64 * v5) >> 39) - (v5 >> 31));
  }
  while ( v3 != &v14 );
  v6 = &v15;                                   
  v15 = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&v9), v15);
  v16 ^= v10;
  LODWORD(v17) = v11 ^ v17;
  WORD2(v17) ^= v12;
  BYTE6(v17) ^= v13;
  do
  {
    v7 = LOBYTE(v6->m128i_i64[0]);
    v6 = (__m128i *)((char *)v6 + 1);
    printf("%.2x ", v7);
  }
  while ( v6 != (__m128i *)((char *)&v17 + 7) );
  return 0;
}
```

In short, it takes a random number from rand() (with time as seed) and xors it with the secret message. I have the cipher text (ctext in my python code). I tried to brute force the code with Z3. It's sat, but the secret message I get it wrong. What could be wrong? I might be doing rookie mistakes so please don't be too harsh. Here is the python 3 code:

```
from z3 import *

# The ciphertext is:
ctext="9a 60 76 14 8b 36 5a 10 2b 91 \
c4 6c ab 27 92 99 f8 6a ec 5d 32 20 3d 61 8f c7 fb dd 02 72 bf"
ctext = ctext.split(' ')

S=Solver()

# We want a message with printable chars
def is_printable(x):
    x = BV2Int(x)
    return And((x>=0x20),
               (x<=0x7e))

key=[]
v5 = BitVec("v5",248) # key
for i in range(0, 248, 8):
    seed_byte = Extract(i + 7, i, v5)
    seed_byte = seed_byte - ((seed_byte * 2139127681) >> 39) - (seed_byte >> 31)
    seed_byte = Extract(7, 0, seed_byte)
    key.append(seed_byte)

message=[]
v15 = BitVec("v15",248) # message
for i in range(0, 248,8):
    message_byte = Extract(i+7,i,v15)
    S.add(is_printable(message_byte))
    message.append(message_byte)

j=0
for i in range(0, 248,8):
    secret = Extract(i+7,i,v15)
    S.add((key[j] ^ secret) == int(ctext[j],16))
    j+=1




print(S.check())
str = S.model()[v15].as_string()
result = hex(int(str,10))[2:]
f=""
for i in range(0,len(result),2):
    f+=chr(int(result[i:i+2],16))
print("The message is: \n" + f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with how you coded this up, but I think there's a more fundamental issue with how you're approaching this problem. At the end, all you are doing is asking Z3 to find you two lists of integers, of length 31 (since 31*8 = 248), such that their elementwise xor is the cipher. And it's doing that perfectly fine. To see, I added the following to your program:

```py
S.check()
m = S.model()

mesg   = [m.eval(i).as_long()  for i in message]
key    = [m.eval(i).as_long()  for i in key]
cipher = [int(i, 16) for i in ctext]
check  = [m ^ k for (m, k) in zip(mesg, key)]
print cipher == check
```

And it prints:

```
True
```

So, the solution is indeed "correct," Z3 did exactly what you asked it to do.

Obviously this is not what you "wanted" it to do! With an XOR based encryption, you'll get an answer for every key and every cipher text. You need further constraints. (Your "ascii-only" constraint is ruling out a bunch of solutions, but again, this is not really focusing on the actual problem.)

So, you have two choices: Iterate over all solutions, and see which one you like, or further constrain the problem somehow to get a unique solution. But neither iis really viable: For the first, the solution space is so vast, your computer (and you) will be long dead before you go through each. For the second, you just don't have enough information from what you've described to get to a unique model.

And this isn't surprising at all: After all, this is in a sense what's known as a "one-time pad" encryption, and it's perfect: There's no information you can glean from the cipher-text that will let you narrow down the search space.

Hope that puts you in the right path. Once you have some other constraints available, we can talk about how to actually code it in z3py. (In particular, you should use BV operations, don't mix integers with bit-vectors, and try not to do assignments like you did. But all of that discussion is moot as the brute-force approach you're using here is just not viable.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood my problem.